# What does an /ActualText of FEFF0009 mean in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-indesign

I've been looking into a PDF file to understand how it is built.

I noticed that InDesign has created PDFs with text as below (after decompression using pdftk).

```
0 Tc /Span<</ActualText<FEFF0009>>> BDC 
4.018 -0.2 Td
( )Tj
```

I understand the role of ActualText (for copy/paste/searching) but I'm wondering exactly how I should be interpreting the FEFF0009. It looks like a UTF-16 string with BOM chars to represent a tab character. This seems incorrect as it's really a space. I'm wondering if there is a special meaning here?

Comment: *a special meaning here* - probably for InDesign but definitively not for the file as a PDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> .. This seems incorrect as it's really a space.

No, it's really a tab.

> **14.9.4 Replacement Text**
>   NOTE 1: Just as alternate descriptions can be provided for images and other items that do not translate naturally into text (as described in the preceding sub-clause), replacement text can be specified for content that does translate into text but that is represented in a nonstandard way.
>   (PDF 32000-1:2008)

The PDF text engine does not support the concept of 'tabs'. In this case, InDesign mimicked the *function* of a tab character by inserting a space in the text stream, and it could set the space width to match the distance spanned by the original tab or use a large relative positioning for the rest of the text (which it did here: the horizontal displacement of `4.018` in your code snippet).

The general idea is that a *space* is rendered on the position of the tab, but when you copy this text and paste somewhere else you get a *tab* character. I suppose the 'space' is only inserted to have something to copy.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense now. I just had another look and I'm also seeing some FEFF0007 (BELL?) characters used in a similar way. It looks like maybe someone has copy/pasted formatting characters when building the document.

Comment: And strangely it seems that copy/paste from Acrobat does not bring the tab across, it uses the space.